Выставление делений шкалы оси графика QWT
Имеется задача перемещения QwtPlotMarker по шкале оси Х объекта QwtPlot. Шаг перемещения QwtPlotMarker задаётся в пикселях (считаю по формуле: qAbs(макс. значение на шкале Х - мин. значение на шкале Х) / ширина области объекта QwtPlot)
Проблема в том, что не понятно, как установить количество делений кратно вычисленному значению шага в пикселях (сейчас при перемещении QwtPlotMarker происходят скачки на 2, 3 и иногда 4 пикселя). Шкала делений автоматически подстраивается под график sin(x)/x из 5000 точек (да и под любой другой), поэтому имеется разброс по шагу QwtPlotMarker.
Есть ощущение, что нужно задействовать метод QwtPlot->setAxisScale(). Присутствует подозрение, что нужно использовать QwtScaleDiv или QwtScaleEngine. Но не очень понятно, как они работают и за что именно отвечают.
